# Translate DataGridComboBoxColumn on the fly

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have got a `DataGridComboBoxColumn` that I need to translate with the `WPFLocalizationExtension`.

I have got a static method in my view model, that provides the available values:

```
public static List<ProfileSegmentType> AvailableSegmentTypes
{
  get
  {
    var availableSegmentTypes = new List<ProfileSegmentType>
    {
      new ProfileSegmentType { Value = ProfileSegmentTypeEnum.Arc },
      new ProfileSegmentType { Value = ProfileSegmentTypeEnum.Line },
    };
    return availableSegmentTypes;
  }
}
```

The `ProfileSegmentType` looks like this:

```
public class ProfileSegmentType
{
  public ProfileSegmentTypeEnum Value { get; set; }
  public string Label
  {
    get { return Resources.Localization.ADummyValue; }
  }
}
```

My data grid column definition looks like this:

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="..."
                        ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Static viewModels:ProfileGeometryViewModel.AvailableSegmentTypes}}"
                        SelectedValueBinding="{Binding SegmentType, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                        SelectedValuePath="Value"
                        DisplayMemberPath="Label" />
```

Now I get labels translated (right now the dummy value). But when I switch the language, the cells are not updated, of course. How can I achieve is, that the cell contents are updated, when I switch the language? (I also tried to use a value converter, but couldn't get it to work this way)

Comment: `List<>` -> `ObservableCollection<>`.

Comment: This does not help me. The list/collection does not change. I also tried to trigger an `OnPropertyChanged(() => AvailableSegmentTypes)`, when the `LocalizaionDictionary` fires an `PropertyChanged`. But the view does not update.

Comment: `ProfileSegmentType` should implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` to reflect changes to `Value` in the view. My previous comment covers the case of modifying collection itself (adding/removing items).

Comment: @Sinatr, even if `ProfileSegmentType` notified its changes, it would need to know if `Resources.Localization` values have changed in the first place. And that's not gonna fly without some work from your side, @stofl. You'll have to add some way to notify your localized classes when the language changes, using some kind of language manager or simply raising some custom transveral events.

Comment: Thank you. That put me on the right trail. I could solve it - see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of your comments, I could solve it. I had to change my `ProfileSegmentType` like so:

```
public class ProfileSegmentType : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  public ProfileSegmentType()
  {
    LocalizeDictionary.Instance.PropertyChanged += (e, a) =>
    {
      if (a.PropertyName == "Culture")
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Label"));
    };
  }
  public ProfileSegmentTypeEnum Value { get; set; }

  public string Label
  {
    get { return Common.Resources.Localization.Add; }
  }

  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = (e, a) => {};
}
```